# Can't Add LINQ to SQL Class from Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql, missing-features

[image]Originally this problem was easy to fix on my local machine by just adding the LINQ to SQL component from the Get Tool and Features menu under Tools, but now I have created a project on Azure Dev Ops so my developer comrades and I can learn how to use Azure Devops.

So, I've created a new solution for the project in the Git repo and connected to our database server and I right click on the Models folder so I can add a LINQ to SQL class and when I bring up the New  Item dialog I have hardly any options and needless to say LINQ to SQL Class is not one of them. I have hardly anything under Installed templates and if I click on "Online" there's just nothing there. And this is one of those things that just kind of hard to google.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I look under "Online" there, there's also just nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a moron, but maybe my stupidity can be your answer. I was looking at the Team Explorer not the Solution Explorer.